# Can't figure Firebase's array example

Tags: firebase

Reading Firebase docs, I'm having a problem understanding [this simultaneously accessed array example](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/understanding-data.html#section-arrays-in-firebase). I can't get the ideal result, nor the problematic one.

Can someone please describe the correct steps by which you get these two results?

Answer (score 0):

Execute this `ref.set(['hello', 'world'])`. **Now go to your Firebase forge.** It will show the structure from the docs.

You've probably followed other steps, such as retrieving the value again with `ref.on('value'`. But as the documentation says, that will revert it back to the original array.

See http://jsfiddle.net/d4tjxL4u/ for the latter behavior. To see the forge, you will have to try the code on your own Firebase.

Comment: I didn't actually try to code it, I just read it step by step, thinking about the result of each step and how it reflects the data set.